# TableView displaying only one cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I am using Dynamic Prototypes with the style `Grouped`. The problem is that table is not populating all the data from array. Here is the screenshot of attribute inspector

[image]

and here is my code

```
class ProductRequestTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var profileImage = ["image1","image2"]
    var userName = ["john doe","john doe"]
    var requestTitle = ["lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.","I have a Wordpress website and I am looking for someone to create a landing page with links and a cart to link up"]
    var date = ["Feb 03, 16","Feb 03, 16"]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return profileImage.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        if(indexPath.row==0){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstProductRequestTableViewCell

            cell.userNameLabel.text = userName[indexPath.row]
            cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileImage[indexPath.row])
            return cell

        }else{




            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondProductRequestTableViewCell

           cell.requestTitleTxtView.text = requestTitle[indexPath.row]
            return cell

                  }
           }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)


    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }



    // Override to support editing the table view.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }



    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }



    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: May be because `profileImage ` have just 1 object in it.

Comment: well Its not the issue. If I hardcode the value it doesn't work also @rptwsthi

Comment: Your counting an array of profile Images. And in your cellforRow your referencing a userName array and a requestTitle array. So what exactly did you hardcore?

Comment: @Devster101 If I hardcode numberof rows thats what I am saying

Comment: It's a convoluted approach.  It appears that you're trying to put a user's name and profile image in one cell, and their request in the next cell. (In effect, you have 2x the number of cells as a user or users.) You might be better off using one table section per user, with each section containing a row for each request by that user.